# ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Config\Reader\Xml\Converter\DeprecatedFormat does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.4, magento-upgrade

Recently I upgrade Magento 2.1.18 to 2.3.4 and got below exception error.

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Config\Reader\Xml\Converter\DeprecatedFormat does not exist

First this error was happen during `setup:upgrade` on **Magento_Amqp** module. I read online that this module is optional and It is okay to disable it.

Now I am getting this exception on checkout page. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you have enterprise folder in you app/etc  then remove and check once

Comment: Great. That works like charm.

Comment: I ran into this exact error on Magento 2.3.4-p2 Commerce, and deleting the `app/etc/enterprise/di.xml` file worked for me as well.